# Django tests, transactions and angular protractor

Tags: python, angularjs, django, selenium, testing

I use django-rest-framework for backend and angularjs for frontend. I started write e2e tests using protractor and faced with a problem, that after each test all changes in database are saved.
In django every test is enclosed in a database transaction that is rolled back at the end of the test. Is there a way to enclose in transaction every protractor test? I know that I can use django live server, python-selenium and write tests in python, but then I lose advantages of protractor.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no universal solution for this problem.

One option is to connect to your database directly from Protractor/Node.js with a database client of your choice and make the necessary database changes before, after or during the tests. You can even use ORMs like `sequelize.js` as an abstraction layer for your database tables. But, since your backend is not Node.js, having two database abstraction layers in two different languages would probably overcomplicate things.

Or, generally *a better way*: you can use your Django REST API in the "set up" and "tear down" phases of your Protractor tests to restore/prepare the necessary database state by making requests to the REST API with an HTTP client, please see more at:

- [Direct Server HTTP Calls in Protractor](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/)